# Grails Hibernate - how to keep data in hibernate cache still my grails application restarted

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

1. I created a new simple project.
2. I created a `Book` domain and mentioned `cache=true` in mapping.
3. I am setting some data by `BootStrap.groovy` configuration.
4. I added some `print` statements in `BootStrap.groovy` to check the data is added or not.
5. I put Hibernate second level cache is true.
6. I run application, it printed in console that "added this many records".
7. But the date not showing in my grid.
8. I tried with postgresSQL, with same data. My grid showing records. Just change in `DataSource.groovy` only.

Please help me, what I am missing

My Default hibernate configuration in `DataSource.groovy`

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    jmxExport = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
//    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
    singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
}
```

**In other words, how to keep data in hibernate cache still my grails application restarted.**
**
**

Comment: actually what is your ..problem...?

Comment: I print Book.count() while starting application. It printed as 272. But after I am trying to get data and print as grid. But it showing zero records. The date it not storing cache, I don't know what exactly it going....

Comment: Hi Ravi. I think you can't save data in the cache of Hibernate and find the data again after a restart. The best you can do is to keep your data in your DB.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but this is for demo purpose. That is, I have to run and show in Jenkins, But Jenkins machine don't have any database server. Else, I have to install Database in Jenkin's machine. that is extra task, because it is just demo application. I hope you understand.